# How to get tags from metadata

Tags: php, image, metadata, exif

Im trying to get the tags from images metadata. Im using exif_read_data function to get the metadata. The result I get for the tags is array -> http://prntscr.com/la1cug. So how I can get the exact tags?

My code -

```
$exif = exif_read_data('test.jpg', 0, true);
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of "Array" means the value of that tag is an array, so you will need a function like print_r:

http://php.net/print_r